# How to insert div before another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to insert a div with class name "section" before the previous div that is above it with the same class name.

Here is the div hierachy

section (1) -> section (2) -> section (3)

I would like to move div with class name section - the third one - before the second one with class name section. I would like to do so dynamically, I want to do the same for other divs, move them before or after the previous or next div with the same class.

What is the best way to do so using jquery?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/before

Comment: Also, please avoid asking for "the best way".  This suggests an opinionated answer.  Simply ask for how to do things, let people answer how they think it should be accomplished, and then you get to pick which one **you** think is the best.

Comment: You should have posted code you tried... With 1,7K rep... You should know this.. You're not a *"new contributor"*.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't even need jQuery for that, you can do it with plain JS using [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) and [`Node.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement):

```js
document.getElementById('move').onclick = () => {
  const sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
  const lastSection = sections[sections.length - 1];
  const sectionBeforeLastSection = lastSection.previousElementSibling;
  
  // Insert lastSection before sectionBeforeLastSection.
  // Note insertBefore is called on the parent element, thus the
  // lastSection.parentElement.
  lastSection.parentElement.insertBefore(lastSection, sectionBeforeLastSection);
};
```

```css
.section {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.a { background: red; }
.b { background: yellow; }
.c { background: cyan; }

#move {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="section a"></div>
<div class="section b "></div>
<div class="section c"></div>

<button id="move">MOVE LAST ONE UP</button>
```

Support for those methods is good and you probably don't need to support older browsers, but you could also do that in a less intuitive way using [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) and [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), which also have slightly better support:

```js
document.getElementById('move').onclick = () => {
  const sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
  const lastSection = sections[sections.length - 1];
  const sectionBeforeLastSection = sections[sections.length - 2];
  
  // Replace sectionBeforeLastSection with lastSection:
  // Note insertBefore is called on the parent element, thus
  // the lastSection.parentElement.
  lastSection.parentElement.replaceChild(lastSection, sectionBeforeLastSection);
  
  // Add sectionBeforeLastSection back at the end:
  // Note we have a wrapping div aroudn the .section divs. Otherwise,
  // appendChild will append the element after the button, as the
  // parent would be the body.
  lastSection.parentElement.appendChild(sectionBeforeLastSection);
};
```

```css
.section {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.a { background: red; }
.b { background: yellow; }
.c { background: cyan; }

#move {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="section a"></div>
  <div class="section b "></div>
  <div class="section c"></div>
</div>

<button id="move">MOVE LAST ONE UP</button>
```